# Form Validation with tabs: jump to first invalid tab

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

this is a follow-up to question [Validation in a form with tabs using nested ng-forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21468664/validation-in-a-form-with-tabs-using-nested-ng-forms).

In this JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/LRfrY/4/ we have a form that won't submit unless all it's subforms are `$valid`. How do make it jump to the first invalid tab when the user tries to submit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found an easy solution so I'll post my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/nicolasmoise/LRfrY/5/

You just add an `ng-click` on your submit button

Note that the `$scope.form1.$valid` variable is undefined when the controller initializes.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is better if you use a directive because you are going to touch the DOM and also because you can group all the logic you need for this form in just one place (you will thank that when your app grows) and the form becomes much more portable as well.

I have changed the form a bit, now it's using just one ngForm and the tabs are normal divs. The form and it's inputs were given names because the ngForm directive needs them to create the formController object.

The directive is listening for clicks on the submit button and we use the formController object to check for errors and react accordingly.

```
.directive('myForm', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function (scope, elm, attrs) {

         var inputs = elm.find('input'), //get all form inputs
             inputTab1 = inputs[0], //asign each input to a var
             inputTab2 = inputs[1],
             submit = inputs[2];

         scope.msg='not submitted';
         scope.tab=1

         //*** ng-form will create a scope var called myForm (myForm is the form's name)

         angular.element(submit).bind('click', function (event) {

              if(scope.myForm.$valid) {
                  //form is valid let it submit
                  scope.$apply(function () {
                    scope.msg = 'submited';
                  });
              }else {
                  //form has erros
                  //event.preventDefault();

                  if(scope.myForm.tab1.$invalid) {
                    scope.$apply(function () {
                        scope.tab = 1;
                        inputTab1.focus();
                    });
                  }else if(scope.myForm.tab2.$invalid) {
                     scope.$apply(function () {
                        scope.tab = 2;
                        inputTab2.focus();
                     });
                  }    
              }
          });
      }
   };
});
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tN8A3/)

If you want to get deeper with Angular's form I recommend [this tutorial](http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/validations.html).

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution. I will definitely try to put the functionality I can re-use in a directive. I do have one issue with yours though. By using  inputTab1 = inputs[0] etc... your directive is tightly tied to your DOM structure which is bad in Angular.

Comment: Agree, the directive would be much better with its own template ;)